# Data validation on a ListBox in WPF

Tags: wpf, validation

I have a ListBox bound to an ObservableCollection of type T - each ListBoxItem is a checkbox with IsChecked bound to a bool property in T. I want to validate the checked items in the ListBox so that at least one checkbox must be ticked - if none of the check boxes are ticked I want to show a red border (standard validation notification) around the ListBox.

How do I go about doing that? Can I use ValidatesOnDataErrors?

Answer (score 1):

Implement `IDataErrorInfo` in the class that exposes the `ObservableCollection<T>` property and make the indexer return an error for that property's name if all of the objects in the collection have a value of `false` in their boolean property.  Then use the `DataErrorValidationRule` in your binding's `ValidationRules`.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. The IDataErrorInfo indexer never gets called for the ObservableCollection<T> property because it isn't changing, only values in T change

Comment: Ugh.  You have to wire up something to raise `PropertyChanged` when the property becomes valid or invalid.  That's a bit more of a hassle.  I'd make the collection's containing class listen to `PropertyChanged` on the items in the collection (assuming they raise it; if they don't, it's even more of a hassle), and revalidate and raise its own `PropertyChanged` event when the `IsChecked` property (whatever it's named) changes on one of the items.  Does that make sense?

Comment: In a way, I have been trying to solve this for 2 weeks. There is very little info out there for validation other than on textboxes. I have decided to not bother with the built-in validation mechanism, it is too messy and poorly conceived. Thanks for your input though.

Comment: What are you doing instead, and what aspect of built-in validation seems poorly conceived?  It seems to me that the messy problem is validating a collection as a whole whenever one of its items changes.

Answer (score 0):

Your goal is to validate selected items of a `ListBox`: at least one selected item is required. First, there are different ways to handle the selection itself:

**a)** You can use the `ListBox` selection mechanism via `ListBox.SelectedItem`.
I guess, you can specifiy the binding as `SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedThing, ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=True}"` and WPF's regular validation works. Not sure, if this works well with multi-selection.

**b)** You can use `ListBox.SelectedItems`. Binding is not possible and needs to be faked via code behind event handler. Thus, WPF's validation cannot trigger here.

**c)** You use your own `IsSelected` property (or similar) per item, either explicitely bound to your viewmodel via `CheckBox` or implicitely via `ListBoxItem.IsSelected` (via `ListBox.ItemContainerStyle`).

From here you could create a `bool IsValidSelection` property in your viewmodel that updates whenever the selection changed. Or you can run validation rules on any of the resulting properties of your viewmodel (e.g. `SelectedItems`). However, you don't validate the bound `ListBox.ItemSource` itself! Therefore WPF's standard mechanisms don't work (the list box doesn't get a red border or whatever).

#### Workarounds

You can explicitely create error notifications by showing an otherwise invisible `Label` and binding its visibility to the above-mentioned `bool IsValidSelection` property. This is a very explicit way, not using WPF validation at all.

You can modify your `INotifyDataErrorInfo` (or similar) implementation to trigger errors on a different property name. This is not possible, if you use a generic `ValidatableViewModel<T>` (like me). I guess this was the intention of the other answer.