# Window with ListBox is not displaying error on the ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, validation

I have a dialog in my WPF application which contains a `ListBox`.  The `ListBox` uses the following `DataTemplate` to display its contents:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="AlarmClassTemplate">
    <CheckBox Content="{Binding Path=Value}"
              IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

I've also configured the following template and style to display when there is an error in the  `ListBox's` contents:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="InputErrorTemplateA">
    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
        <Image DockPanel.Dock="Right"
               Height="30"
               Margin="5"
               Source="{StaticResource ErrorImage}"
               ToolTip="Contains invalid data"
               VerticalAlignment="Center"
               Width="30" />
        <Border BorderBrush="Red"
                BorderThickness="5"
                Margin="5">
            <AdornedElementPlaceholder />
        </Border>
    </DockPanel>
</ControlTemplate>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
    <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate" Value="{StaticResource InputErrorTemplateA}" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="ToolTip">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <Binding Path="(Validation.Errors).CurrentItem.ErrorContent" RelativeSource="{x:Static RelativeSource.Self}" />
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

And here's the XAML for the `ListBox` itself:

```
<ListBox FontSize="20"
         FontWeight="Bold"
         Grid.Column="1"
         Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
         Grid.Row="1"
         Height="158"
         ItemsSource="{Binding Path=IDs, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"
         ItemTemplate="{StaticResource AlarmClassTemplate}"
         Margin="5,0,110,0"
         Name="AlarmClassListBox"
         ToolTip="{x:Static res:Car.EditDataRetention_AlarmClasses_ToolTip}"
         Visibility="{Binding Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibility}, Path=DataTypeIsAlarms}" />
```

The validation logic for the data in the `ListBox` is that at least one item has to be checked off.  If none of them are, the `ListBox` should display an error and the `OK` button on the dialog should be disabled.

The good news is that the `OK` button on the dialog is indeed disabled when nothing in the `ListBox` is checked.  The bad news is that the `Style` doesn't seem to be working, in that no red border is displayed around the `ListBox` and the error image (a red circle with a white exclamation point inside) does not show.

I'm using the same exact `ControlTempate` and a similar `Style` on other controls on the same dialog and they work fine.  What am I doing wrong?  Is it the `ListBox`?  Does `ListBox` validation work differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my problem [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4430580/data-validation-on-a-listbox-in-wpf).  It turns out that I have to raise the `PropertyChanged` event when the checkboxes change in order for the Validation logic to fire.  Since the items in the `ListBox` implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, it was easy to add an event listener for each item as it's added to the `ListBox` which raises the necessary event.

Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed the problem is you weren't raising `PropertyChanged` event for your validation to gets fired.

But i can see one more issue in your code. You have set local value for tooltip on ListBox here:

```
ToolTip="{x:Static res:Car.EditDataRetention_AlarmClasses_ToolTip}"
```

But you want different tooltip in case validation returns some error which you define in style triggers.

But, **local value has higher precedence order than style triggers**. So, your tooltip will never be set. So, you should move the tooltip to style setters to work:

```
<Setter Property="ToolTip"
        Value="{x:Static res:Car.EditDataRetention_AlarmClasses_ToolTip}"/>
```

MSDN link - [Dependency property value precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Thank you, I hadn't forgotten about the precedence!